# Create date object and compare to todays date

Tags: javascript, date

I have an object containing time. For example `x.time = 10:20:00`.
I want to take the current time minus my objects time.

This is my code so far, but i get the error message ="Invalid Date":

```
for(var i = 0; i<x.length; i++){
    nowDate = new Date();
    minutesLeft = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(),    nowDate.getDate() + x[i].time);
    text +- "It is "+ minutesLeft[i] + " milliseconds left";
 }
```

Comment: _it is complaining at my code_ How ?

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) **must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._

Comment: @AxelH Oh sorry. It is says: Invalid Date

Comment: And how can we reproduce this ? What is `x` values (an array? ) ? `time` is a String ? and your last line should be in the loop if you want to use `i`

Comment: @AxelH The x values are fetched from a API which a get in JSON. The value i´m using is time and the format is always "00:00:00"

Comment: `text +- = "..."` <-- what are you expecting that `+-` to do?

Comment: You are trying to set the date of your new date to `1910:20:00` because `time` is a text value

Comment: @AxelH. I see. But how to i use this string to create new date()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to convert your time property into a date object you can do:

```
var timepieces = x.time.split(':');
var date = new Date();
date.setHours(timepieces[0]);
date.setMinutes(timepieces[1]);
date.setSeconds(timepieces[2]);
```

Then you can directly compare the two dates by using the `getTime()` method of the `Date` object.

```
nowDate.getTime() === date.getTime()
nowDate.getTime() > date.getTime()
nowDate.getTime() < date.getTime()
```

You can also get the difference of two dates in milliseconds:

```
var milliseconds = nowDate.getTime() - date.getTime();
```

Comment: He will need to convert his `x` String into a date too.

Comment: @AxelH I updated my answer on converting the time property into a date object with the current date.

Comment: Looks perfect for me. You have my vote. (I was lazy to write the solution, my `javascript` is a bit rusty)

Comment: @AxelH Somebody else is still downvoting me :P

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of problems with your code. I'll go through and hopefully catch everything.

1. Use `var` to declare your variables inside your loop. ([further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it))
2. When you create the variable `minutesLeft` you are doing a bit of weird concatenation. You told us that `x.time` is a string such as "10:20:00" but you are (string) concatenating that with [`Date.prototype.getDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) which returns a number in the range 1-31 (representing the day of the month). You are essentially doing this:

   ```
   minutesLeft = new Date(2017,0,1910:20:00);
   ```

   Which I hope you see will not create a new date. You perhaps wanted something along the lines of

   ```
   minutesLeft = new Date(2017,0,19, 10, 20, 0);
   ```

   Which should give you what you want (todays date set to the appropriate time defined by `x.time`.
3. `text +-` does not make any sense. I suspect a typo, you meant `text +=` which will append the value on the right to the variable `text`. Or, perhaps `text =` which will assign the value, replacing what was there
4. `"It is "+ minutesLeft[i] + " milliseconds left"` using `minutesLeft[i]` will take a single character from a string (or an item from an array, if the value is an array). Yours is just a date object, and is not an array, so I suspect you just meant to leave off the `[i]` part altogether.
5. If you're trying to get the difference between the current date/time and your selected date/time you need to do some arithmetic with `nowDate` and `minutesLeft`. I'm assuming this is a difference you're after.

---

```js
var x = [{time:"10:20:20"}];
var text = "";
for(var i = 0; i<x.length; i++){
    var nowDate = new Date();
    var timeSplit = x[i].time.split(":");
    var minutesLeft = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(),    nowDate.getDate());
    minutesLeft.setHours(timeSplit[0]);
    minutesLeft.setMinutes(timeSplit[1]);
    minutesLeft.setSeconds(timeSplit[2]);
    text += "It is "+ (nowDate-minutesLeft) + " milliseconds left";
 }

console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

> For example x.time = 10:20:00. I want to take the current time minus my objects time.

Your code seems quite confused, it seems you're trying to do the following:

```js
var time = '10:20:00';
var timeParts = time.split(':');
var now = new Date();

// Current date and time
console.log(now.toString());

// Subtract the hours part of the time from the hours part of the current time
now.setHours(now.getHours() - timeParts[0]);

// Subtract the minutes part of the time from the minutes part of the current time
now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() - timeParts[1]);

// Subtract the seconds part of the time from the seconds part of the current time
now.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() - timeParts[2]);

// Adjusted date and time
console.log(now.toString());

// You can set the time parts all in one go:
var now2 = new Date();
now2.setHours(now2.getHours() - timeParts[0],
              now2.getMinutes() - timeParts[1],
              now2.getSeconds() - timeParts[2]);
console.log(now2.toString());
```

Lastly, copying a date is as simple as:

```
var date1 = new Date();
var date2 = new Date(date1);
```